# Google Analytics regex doesn't replace multiple instances of an expression

Tags: regex, filter, replace, google-analytics

I want to setup a filter and replace on URI in my Google Analytics account and I want to filter "/" sperated values from URI:
This is a sample list of URIs:

```
/clients/1282/buildings/4490
/clients/1362/buildings/8915/systems
/clients/1362/buildings/8915/systems/manage-rules/configure-rules
/clients/1282/buildings/4490/insights/rule-templates
/clients/1167/buildings/4126/insights/4126.10100.PG1-Program_Data
```

this is the regex I apply the moment but it captures only the first instance and it doesn't work for the last URI (mix of text and numbers)

```
(\/)\d+
```

results of the current state is :

```
/clients/1282/buildings/4490
/clients/1362/buildings/8915/systems
/clients/1362/buildings/8915/systems/manage-rules/configure-rules
/clients/1282/buildings/4490/insights/rule-templates
/clients/1167/buildings/4126/insights/4126.10100.PG1-Program_Data
```

expected result

```
/clients/buildings/
/clients/buildings/systems
/clients/buildings/systems/manage-rules/configure-rules
/clients/buildings/insights/rule-templates
/clients/buildings/insights/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one Search and Replace for the first group and another for the second group.